# Issues with handling ON_WM_NCPAINT() message and OnNCPaint() override. (Overriding default MFC window border) [2020]

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, windows-messages, cdialog

I'm attempting to create a "dark mode" theme for my Windows app, and I'm experiencing some inconsistencies with overriding the OnNcPaint() function. Please pardon the giant red box. I'm only coloring it in that way to show the issue.

Here's my initial function:

```
void CSoftwareDlg::OnNcPaint() {
    Default(); //I can also use "CDialgoEx::OnNcPaint();" here for the same result because it just calls "Default..."

    CDC* pDC = GetWindowDC();
    CRect rect;
    GetWindowRect(&rect);
    rect.top = 0;
    rect.left = 0;
    rect.bottom = rect.Size().cy;
    rect.right = rect.Size().cx;
    pDC->FillRect(rect, &m_brushRed);
    
    ReleaseDC(pDC);
}
```

And the (usual) result:
[image: with Default]

I can partially resolve this issue by removing the call to `Default();`:
[image: without Default]

...But anytime the window is moved(or redrawn I guess):
[image: border redraws itself]

I can also add a `Sleep(1000);` to achieve somewhat different results, but it's not worth posting a picture. Ultimately... My override isn't really "overriding" as it should based on the numerous pieces of sample code I've taken a look at. I know that `Default();` is some kind of threaded callback function, but I have no idea how to troubleshoot this issue any further.

Do I need to perform some kind of wait for the `Default();` command? Do I need to implement `OnNcPaint()` as some kind of callback function? Are there additional functions I need to be overriding?

Comment: There's at least one resource leak. For each successful call to [CWnd::GetWindowDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getwindowdc) *"[ReleaseDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#releasedc) should be called"*. Resource leaks can have all sorts of funky effects, particularly with very limited resources such as [GDI objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/gdi-objects).

Comment: Thank you, fixed.

Comment: That does cause a *very minor* change in behavior, but ultimately the disappearing/reappearing frame/border(?) is still still an issue.

Comment: You will need to override [`WM_NCACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-ncactivate) as well, which "*draws the title bar or icon title*".

Answer (score 1):

As @dxiv said that, please handle `WM_NCACTIVATE` message,

Like this(under win32),

```
 case WM_NCACTIVATE:
    {
        // Paint the non-client area now, otherwise Windows will paint its own
        RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_UPDATENOW);
    }
        break;
```

Not sure if your client area also needs to maintain the same color.

If necessary, you can additionally handle the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message.